# Can you lock multiple magnets to a single superconducting puck?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, superconductivity

We've all seen the videos of a superconducting puck floating above a track of magnets. Could another magnet be locked above the puck? I ask this with the intention of attaching vacuum insulator to the magnet above the puck which surrounds the puck so the puck can stay cool while on traveling on the track.